# Django DisallowedHost at /, adding it causes connection to be refused

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web, debian

I'm facing a Django DisallowedHost error, googling the solution lead me to add the domains in question to the ALLOWED_HOSTS list in settings.py.

However, doing so causes the connection to flat out refuse to connect, and seemingly force https.

DisallowedHost Error log:

https://pastebin.com/sEg73qmV

```
django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.davixxa.net'. You may need to add 'www.davixxa.net' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

This being the specific error of interest.

Settings.py: https://pastebin.com/1Mz9xNSC

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have missconfiguration

hostname in [ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) sorted accessing site from the following host but

considering you have been forced to https you should set to false [SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT) setting which enforces https

Comment: I'm not quite getting what you're trying to say? Are you telling me to add the hosts to the list? I've gone ahead and done this, and that fetches me a simple [connection refused (screenshot)](https://i.imgur.com/wWSqqsy.png) error.

Comment: as you can see seems you have SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT set to true as HTTP request redirects you from http to https you should put following setting to false to remove following behaviour

Comment: I've tried manually setting it to false in settings.py (it wasn't set before), and it seems to make no difference.

Comment: Alright. https redirect issue is fixed, used this solution: https://superuser.com/questions/565409/chrome-how-to-stop-redirect-from-http-to-https to fix that. Now I'm just left with Django not liking MySQL though.